# Clip PostGIS raster to region that crosses 180 meridian

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I am using `postgis 2.5`'s raster to store global geographical data (weather forecast) in `EPSG:4326` projection, using 0.25° resolution. I use tiling. I created queries to clip the global data to given region and dump them into PNG. This works fine, but I run into trouble, when I want to get data for region that transverse the 180 meridian (for example, a map that shows Hawaii on the right side and Japan on the left side).

I tried to use `ST_WrapX` and `ST_ShiftLongitude` functions, but the problem is that they both take and return `geometry` instance, which has to be then converted to raster using `ST_AsRaster` function, to be passed into `ST_AsPNG`; which just seems as too much trouble for such simple operation. It is obviously also possible to get the two regions on the sides of 180 meridian separately and stitch them together later, but that also seems too much hassle.

Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Below is simplified version of queries I am using to output the data, for Europe region. Note that I am actually calling the queries from `python` (`psycopg2`), so I `write` fetched result into PNG file directly.

```
/* Get the data, merge tiles, clip to wanted region and transform to EPSG:3857*/
SELECT ST_Transform(
              ST_Clip((SELECT ST_Union(rast) FROM raster_data
                       CROSS JOIN
                       ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 30, 60, 72, 4326) as geom
                       WHERE element = 'temperature_2m' AND ST_Intersects(rast, geom)),
                      ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 30, 60, 72, 4326), true), 3857)
         INTO TEMPORARY clipped_result;

/* Define colormap and use it to output the data as png */
SELECT ST_AsPNG(ST_ColorMap((SELECT * FROM clipped_result),
                '''100%:251, 19, 19, 157
                   50%:252, 128, 20, 157
                   0%:130, 22, 146, 157'''));
```